# Autofilter with more than two criteria using logic operators

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter out / hide rows containing these keywords in column "B". This is what I have so far, but the autofilter allows only 2 criterias. How do I get around this limitation?

```
Sub removeMisc()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>*ABC*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<>*DEF*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria3:="<>*GHI*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria4:="<>*JKL*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria5:="<>*MNO*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria6:="<>*PQR*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria7:="<>*STU*"
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: - loop through the column and deselect the individual entries based on the criteria; - use the Advanced Filter

Answer (score 1):

### Filter Using 'Hidden'

- The 3rd Sub (`filterWorksheet`) is the main Sub. The Subs below it
  are being called by it.
- The 1st Sub is showing how to use the main Sub for one worksheet,
  while the 2nd Sub is showing how to use the main Sub for all
  worksheets in a workbook.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub runFilterWorksheet()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const FilterColumn As Variant = "B" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const ignoreCase As Boolean = True  ' 'True' means A = a
    Dim HideCriteria As Variant: HideCriteria = Array("ABC", "DEF") ' Add more.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    filterWorksheet ws, HideCriteria, FirstRow, FilterColumn, ignoreCase
    
End Sub

Sub runFilterAll()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const FilterColumn As Variant = "B" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const ignoreCase As Boolean = False ' 'False' means A <> a
    Dim HideCriteria As Variant: HideCriteria = Array("ABC", "DEF") ' Add more.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        filterWorksheet ws, HideCriteria, FirstRow, _
                             FilterColumn, ignoreCase
    Next ws
    
End Sub

Sub filterWorksheet(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                    HideCriteria As Variant, _
                    Optional FirstRow As Long = 1, _
                    Optional FilterColumn As Variant = 1, _
                    Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    getColumn Data, Sheet, FilterColumn, FirstRow
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim RowOffset As Long: RowOffset = FirstRow - 1 ' 1 = LBound(Data)
    Dim RowNumbers() As Long
    collectRowNumbers RowNumbers, Data, HideCriteria, _
                      RowOffset, ignoreCase
    If IsEmpty(RowNumbers) Then Exit Sub

    hideRows Sheet, RowNumbers
    
End Sub

Sub getColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
              Sheet As Worksheet, _
              Optional ColumnID As Variant = 1, _
              Optional FirstRow As Long = 1)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(ColumnID).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row > FirstRow Then
        Data = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, ColumnID), rng).Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
End Sub
               
Sub collectRowNumbers(ByRef RowNumbers() As Long, _
                      ColumnArray2D As Variant, _
                      Criteria As Variant, _
                      RowOffset As Long, _
                      Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim iCase As Long
    If ignoreCase Then iCase = 1
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long: k = -1 ' -1 = UBound(RowNumbers)
    For i = 1 To UBound(ColumnArray2D)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Criteria)
            If InStr(1, ColumnArray2D(i, 1), Criteria(j), iCase) > 0 Then
                GoSub writeData
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
writeData:
    k = k + 1
    If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve RowNumbers(k)
    Else
        ReDim RowNumbers(0)
    End If
    RowNumbers(k) = i + RowOffset
    Return
    
End Sub

Sub hideRows(Sheet As Worksheet, RowNumbers As Variant)
    
    Dim rng As Range, j As Long
    
    For j = 0 To UBound(RowNumbers)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = Union(rng, Sheet.Rows(RowNumbers(j)))
        Else
            Set rng = Sheet.Rows(RowNumbers(0))
        End If
    Next j
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked a few times but simple answer is: if you want to filter a range with more than 2 criteria where you want to hide rows based on where the criteria doesn't match, you cannot do that (well not with VBA anyway.. to my knowledge). So I decided to see if i can write something that would allow you to do that...

**And here it is**

So the below UDF behaves like a filter but in actual fact it just hides the rows based on the criteria specified. So if you want to filter rows based on: the specified text does not exist in the cell (of a particular column), below should do the trick:

```
Sub MultiAutoFilter(ByVal oFilterRng As Range, ByVal iColumn As Long, ByVal aCriteria As Variant)
    
    Dim aFilter As Variant, sElement As Variant
    Dim iStartRow As Long, iC As Long
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    
    ' Use the worksheet of specified range
    With oFilterRng.Parent
        
        ' Clear any existing filters
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        ' Capture start row and copy range to an array
        iStartRow = oFilterRng.Cells(1, 1).Row
        aFilter = oFilterRng
        
        ' Loop through the range to be filtered
        For iC = UBound(aFilter) To LBound(aFilter) Step -1
            
            ' Loop through all elements specified in aCriteria array (NOTE: aCriteria has to be a single dimensional array)
            bFound = False
            For Each sElement In aCriteria
        
                Select Case InStr(1, CStr(sElement), "*", vbTextCompare)
                    Case Is > 0
                        If aFilter(iC, iColumn) Like CStr(sElement) Then
                            bFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Case Else
                        If aFilter(iC, iColumn) = CStr(sElement) Then
                            bFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                End Select
                
            Next
            
            ' If specified text was not found then hide the row
            If Not bFound Then
                .Cells(iStartRow + (iC - 1), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
            
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```

**How to use the UDF:**
Below is an example of how you can use the above UDF:

```
Sub JustTeting()
    
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")        '<- Change to the sheet name
    Dim oFilterRange As Range: Set oFilterRange = oWS.Range("A2:B11")        '<- Set your range here
    Dim aCriteria As Variant: aCriteria = Array("*us*", "to", "multi")       '<- This is the single dimensional array setup for Criteria
    
    MultiAutoFilter oFilterRange, 1, aCriteria                            '<- This is how you can call the UDF
    
End Sub
```

Something to consider here is that as the rows are hidden (and not filtered), how would you unhide the hidden rows. You can easily do this manually or if you are like me and want a UDF to do that.. here it is:

```
Sub ClearMultiFilter(ByVal oWS As Worksheet)
    
    oWS.Rows.Hidden = False
    
End Sub
```

To use this UDF, you simply do the following:

```
ClearMultiFilter ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")      '<- Change the sheet name to the sheet that has hidden rows
```

Answer (score 1):

rayep19064, I tried to put comment next to your one, but I'm not allowed to do it.
In romulax14's answer/code, operator `Operator:=xlFilterValues` should work for you (not `xlAnd`).

So, entire (with proper operator for you) romulax14's code:

```
Sub mSub()
    Dim mArray(2) As String
    mArray(0) = "Gondor"
    mArray(1) = "Westfold"
    mArray(2) = "Rohan"
    
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=mArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put every criteria in a String Array and use the array as the AutoFilter Criteria.
Something like :

```
Sub mSub()
    Dim mArray(2) As String
    mArray(0) = "Gondor"
    mArray(1) = "Westfold"
    mArray(2) = "Rohan"
    
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=mArray, Operator:="whaterver your operator should be"
End Sub
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter#example).

Comment: I used your example like, `myArray(0) = "<>*ABC*"`, and `Operator:=xlAnd`. But, only the last string in the array is filtered out. I think that each time it iterates through the array, the filter gets reset